# Count lines of code by user.email in a git repository

Tags: bash, git, shell

In a git repository, how do I count the lines of code written by an author based on his/her user.email not his/her user.name

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks, this is about git in general, not just about some specific pieces of code.